# RTAI-3.8 installation stacked in ubuntu-12.04(x64)+linux-kernel-2.6.32.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, installation, rtai

I cannot complete installation of RTAI-3.8 in ubuntu-12.04(x64)+linux-kernel-2.6.32.2.

I am trying to install RTAI on new PC. 
Make succeeded in the linux kernel configuration that worked fine in another PC. 
However, restart failed after "make install". 
Specific symptoms do not reach the login screen after select RTAI-patched linux in grub. 
This is the same symptoms in Safe Mode.

In the linux kernel configuration

```
- Processor type and features 
    ---> Processor family
```

There was no pattern that was successful even if in any the. 
Number of CPU cores is similar.

It is a situation you do not know what the cause. 
Or Will there be hardware such as a CPU or motherboard RTAI does not support? 
My PC is Pro5500-H Endeavor. Specs are as follows.

```
CPU: intel Core 17-4770K@3.50GHz x8 
motherboard:. EPSON DIRECT CORP Pro5500-H
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use newer versions of the available software. Why not use Ubuntu 14.04 and RTAI 4.0 (recently 4.1 was also released)?

That said, RTAI-enabled kernel configuration requires a lot of playing around. Each piece of hardware may have its own issues that may not play well with RTAI.

There are people who have tried making debian packages for RTAI though, and in my experience it has worked great.  This is instruction from the author (John Morris):

```
(replace 'wheezy' with 'jessie' if applicable)

# Install the Dovetail Automata archive signing keys
wget http://deb.dovetail-automata.com/pool/main/d/dovetail-automata-keyring/dovetail-automata-keyring_0.1-1~wheezy1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i dovetail-automata-keyring_0.1-1~wheezy1_all.deb

# Configure the archive sources
echo "deb http://deb.dovetail-automata.com wheezy main" |\
    sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/machinekit.list'

# Update package indexes
apt-get update

# Install packages
apt-get install librtai1 librtai-dev
#     amd64 architecture:
apt-get install \
  linux-image-rtai.x86-amd64 linux-headers-rtai.x86-amd64
#     i386 architecture:
apt-get install \
  linux-image-rtai.x86-i686-pae linux-headers-rtai.x86-i686-pae
```

With Ubuntu 14.04, replace `wheezy` with `trusty`. This installs both the RTAI-enabled kernel (the two last commands) and the RTAI library (first `apt-get install`). If you want your own configuration for RTAI, you can simply just install the kernel and build your own library.